# List forms in Infopath 2010

Tags: infopath

In SP2010, I created a list and used Infopath 2010 to edit the list form inorder to apply some validations and maintain look and feel. 
In Infopath, I assigned date column to Today, so that whenever a user fills in the form it auto populates today's date.
I problem which I'm getting is that the format of date is changed when I publish the form. ie., instead of display 01/12/2011 its displaying 2011-12-01. 
I double checked the "My regional settings" in sharepoint and also in infopath date picker properties. Is there any thing else I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try `now()` function, not `Today()`.